# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't shutdown or restart

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed in an HP notebook. I started with Windows 7. Everything is OK with Windows 7. The problem is with Ubuntu. The problem started when I noticed Ubuntu was unable to shutdown correctly. I mean, show the screen of power off, but it freezes. And finally, I pressed the button on/off to force the shutdown.

I bear this problem through this time, but this week I had the chance and time to format my notebook and reinstall Ubuntu.
I downloaded Ubuntu 17.10 and installed it. Started other trouble with Ubuntu 17.10. It hangs frozen suddenly, I can't do anything, neither can I open the terminal.
Then I reformatted the hard drive again, I reinstalled the old Ubuntu 16.04 from a bootable pen drive.

I began the test, the problem of shutting and restarting is continuing!
Now I don't know what more to do.

The features of my notebook, maybe are useful (HP 15, 500GB hard disk 4GB RAM)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: There are thousands of "notebook hp"... Does your have a Nvidia graphics card? Better [edit] and post hardware specifications.

Comment: I just have a external drive containing all my data, may be is a hardware problem. But I have another external disk with WIndows 7, I started with this, all is ok. The problem is ubuntu. Anyway thanks for your advice

Comment: I will follow your post. Because I too face similar problem and trying to find solution. I have acer e 15  E-575G. I have only ubuntu In my laptop. Due to similar issue I have reinstalled 16.04 from 17.10. Still some times freezes.

Comment: Actually the problem is your hardware not being Linux friendly. Avoid any X or Z series.

Comment: Two days ago I tried to restart the notebook and works!, then I tried to shutdown, and it works too!, but minutes later of tests, The same problem came back. Sincerely It is bothering me. Is there any ubuntu version or linux distr. that can work regarding my notebook features?